# SQL Server 2008 Report Builder source code or application which looks like that

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, reportviewer, reportviewer2008

I am kinda addicted to report viewer and reporting tool, almost all my applications needs reports and I am most familiar with RDLC or RDL languages for making reports.

Microsoft Report Builder v3 is great application, and I want to share that goodies with my end users, is there source of that application available for developers, or is there other open source application which can be hosted inside winforms application or edited so I can add more features as users needs which looks like ReportBuilder app.

I will like to share only viewing of reports with end users without needs for design reports. I know that I can use report viewer control in my winforms application to work with RDLC files, but report builder app has a lot of better look then reportviewer control.

To be clear please take look at [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk2PB.jpg) [image: picture]

Comment: I'm interested in this topic now, after 1 year you've posted it. May I know if you were able to find a good _source_?

Comment: @AlexR. Only think that I fun so far is library for ribbon that looks similar to this http://fluent.codeplex.com/

Comment: That's rather depressing. But thanks, I am trying to build a similar one myself. It's a chunk of work, but it is usable to a certain level. I won't be employing a ribbon control though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure i completely understand what you're asking.  However, if you install Reporting Services on your SQL Server instance you can create a report site that you can then deploy reports to and set up security to allow people to see reports there.

Also with Reporting Services you can create models on different subsets of data and allow certain people access to those, who can then use report builder to make their own report.  As far as i am aware you have to install report builder seperately on each machine.

Answer (score 0):

The Report Builder and the Report Viewer serve two entirely different purposes. What need is there to have a ribbon bar in the Report Viewer? The user doesn't need all those options. The purpose of the Report Viewer is to display reports, pure and simple.

Comment: Beside of ribbon bar, I also need to add controls for controlling reports as print, export and others. So before I star making my own ribbon for controlling reports I was hooping that there is something already done before I start coding my own report viewer controls and buttons

Comment: Q:"What need is there to have a ribbon bar in the Report Viewer?"   A: A lot of end users is low skills with applications, I realized that when I saw that I have users which printing reports from IE menu not using small printer inside toolbar of reportviewer control, or did not know that they can zoom or search reports. I want to show reportviewer functions in more absorbing way

Comment: @adopiolot - The Report Viewer already has a toolbar that allows the user to Print, Export, Zoom and other things. Why reinvent the wheel? It doesn't take a rocket scientist to be able to figure out how to click on these buttons to say export a report.